# How do I add data from a form with a variable number of rows into a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, variables

I have a form in two sections on a webpage.  Each section contains a variable number of rows (the user can add more rows).  I have a PHP page which processes the form as an email, but I am now looking to extend this so that information is added to a My SQL database that I have in place.  Below is the code for the form and the php processing page as it stands.

I have started to include the code for submitting the data to the MySQL table at the bottom of the PHP page, but I am not sure how to do this, given that there are a variable number of rows in two sections, and would be grateful for any help in getting this working.

Here is the HTML for the form:

```
<form method="post" name="booking" action="bookingengine.php">
    <fieldset>
        <h2>Waged/Organisation Rate</h2>
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="name[]">
            <input type="text" name="email[]">
            <input type="text" name="organisation[]">
            <input type="text" name="position[]">
        </p>
        <p><span class="add">Add person</span></p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2>Unwaged Rate</h2>
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="name2[]">
            <input type="text" name="email2[]">
        </p>
        <p><span class="add">Add person</span></p>
    </fieldset>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit and proceed to payment page" class="submit-button" /></p>

</form>
```

And here is the booking engine.php:

```
<? include 'connection.php'; ?>

<?php

$emailFrom = "****";
$emailTo = "****";
$subject = "Booking for Soteria Conference";

$body = "The following people have booked for the Soteria Conference in Derby:" . "\n\n" . "Waged/Organisation Rate:" . "\n\n";
$row_count = count($_POST['name']);
$row_count2 = count($_POST['name2']);



for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++)
{
  // variable sanitation...
  $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'][$i]));
  $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'][$i]));
  $organisation = trim(stripslashes($_POST['organisation'][$i]));
  $position = trim(stripslashes($_POST['position'][$i]));

  // this assumes name, email, and telephone are required & present in each element
  // otherwise you will have spurious line breaks. 
  $body .= "Name: " . $name . "    Email: " . $email . "  Organisation: " . $organisation . "   Position: " . $position . "\n\n";
}

$body .= "Unwaged Rate:" . "\n\n";

for($j = 0; $j < $row_count2; $j++)
{
  // variable sanitation...
  $name2 = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name2'][$j]));
  $email2 = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email2'][$j]));

  // this assumes name, email, and telephone are required & present in each element
  // otherwise you will have spurious line breaks. 
  $body .= "Name: " . $name2 . "    Email: " . $email2 . "\n\n";
}

// send email 
$success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, "From: <$emailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=payment.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}

?>
```

Here is the structure of connection.php:

```
<?php

$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "****";
$username = "****";
$password = "****";

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($database);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean. But your HTML code should be more like this :

```
<p>
  <input type="text" name="persons[][name]">
  <input type="text" name="persons[][email]">
  <input type="text" name="persons[][organisation]">
  <input type="text" name="persons[][position]">
</p>
```

And then at the end of your PHP script

```
$values = array();
foreach ($_POST['persons'] as $person) {
    // Sanitize your datas
    ...
    // SQL VALUES TO INSERT
    $values[] = '(' . $person['name'] . ',' . $person['email'] . ',' . $person['organisation'] . ',' . $person['position'] . ')';
}
$query = "INSERT INTO person (name, email, organization, position) VALUES " . implode(',', $values);
```

The same logic applies for Unwaged rates

edit if you want to keep your HTML

```
 $values = array();

 for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
     // variable sanitation...
     $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'][$i]));
     $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'][$i]));
     $organisation = trim(stripslashes($_POST['organisation'][$i]));
     $position = trim(stripslashes($_POST['position'][$i]));

     // this assumes name, email, and telephone are required & present in each element
     // otherwise you will have spurious line breaks. 
     $body .= "Name: " . $name . "    Email: " . $email . "  Organisation: " . $organisation . "   Position: " . $position . "\n\n";

     //prepare the values for MySQL
     $values[] = '(' . $name . ',' . $email . ',' . $organisation . ',' . $position . ')';
}
$query = "INSERT INTO person (name, email, organization, position) VALUES " . implode(',', $values);

 And for unwaged rate

 $values = array();

 for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) {
     // variable sanitation...
     $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'][$i]));
     $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'][$i]));

     // this assumes name, email, and telephone are required & present in each element
     // otherwise you will have spurious line breaks. 
     $body .= "Name: " . $name . "    Email: " . $email . "\n\n";

     //prepare the values for MySQL
     $values[] = '(' . $name . ',' . $email . ')';
}
$query = "INSERT INTO person (name, email) VALUES " . implode(',', $values);
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify.  The page with the booking system on can be seen [here](http://www.soterianetwork.org.uk/conference/index.html).  I have a MySQL database with 4 columns: 'Name', 'Email', 'Organisation' and 'Position'.  I would like the data submitted on the form (which has a variable number of rows for each section) to be added to the database.  Because there is a variable number of rows I am not sure how to construct the PHP to enter all the necessary data.

Comment: I clarified my code. Your page is quite clean :) But for the html for you should name your values more like I told you. So it will be easier for you to access them in the php code `foreach ($_POST['persons'] as $person) { ... }` And the SQL request should look like the one I told you, you can insert several rows like that `INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3), (val1, val2, val3) ... etc Don't know if it answers your question?

Comment: Thanks again.  I think you are answering my question, but I am not very clever with PHP so I am still a bit confused!  Are you suggesting I replace `for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++)`... with `foreach ($_POST['persons'] as $person) {`....?  It seems to me that you are not just suggesting an addition to the code I already have (so that data can be submitted to MySQL), but are also suggesting a change to the code that constructs the email.  Is this so?

Comment: Many Thanks.  We are getting there.  I have everything set up with the code you included in which I keep my HTML.  The email gets sent fine, but nothing is being added to my MySQL database.  I have now included the connection.php at the bottom of my original question, in case this is the issue.  I am sure that all of the settings are correct.  In the main PHP page I simply have `<? include 'connection.php'; ?>` at the top.  I thought this was all I needed to do to make a connection.

Comment: How are you making your SQL request ?

Comment: Probably showing my limited knowledge of MySQL here. I just have the connection.php file which I have included the contents of above.  Then I have included this at the top of my main PHP file and then your code. Am I missing something?

Comment: I now have this sorted.  I was not actually running the queries.  I sorted this out in a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940367/why-is-my-data-not-submitted-to-mysql-database).  Thanks for your help.  I have marked the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple inputs, I recommend using multidimensional arrays (which you're currently doing - but not effectively):

```
<fieldset id="1">
   <legend>Row 1</legend>
   <input type="text" name="name[1]"/>
   <input type="text" name="email[1]"/>
   <input type="text" name="address[1]"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="2">
   <legend>Row 2</legend>
   <input type="text" name="name[2]"/>
   <input type="text" name="email[2]"/>
   <input type="text" name="address[2]"/>
</fieldset>
```

You can use JavaScript (like jQuery) to append more rows (if they click on a button for example).  You can use the fieldset ID to populate the array key for the new row.  Here's the PHP I'd use:

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $row_number => $value){
   $query = 'INSERT INTO table (name' . $row_number . ', user_id) VALUES (' . $value . ', ' . $user_id . ')';  
}
```

If you're expecting **lots** of rows, you can set up a table that lists each name as a separate row (with a `user_id` column) rather than as a column in a table that lists rows per user.  So instead of doing:

```
user_id | name1 | name2 | name 3

1 | James | John | Jimbob
2 | Sandy | Samm | Sandra
```

You can do:

```
id | order | user_id | value

1 | 1 | 1 | James
2 | 2 | 1 | John
3 | 3 | 1 | Jimbob
4 | 1 | 2 | Sandy
5 | 2 | 2 | Samm
6 | 3 | 2 | Sandra
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just to clarify.  The page with the booking system on can be seen here. I already have a method of adding rows to each section of the form as you can see, and a method of emailing the data from the form.  Now I would like to get the form linked up to my MySQL database.  I have a database with 4 columns: 'Name', 'Email', 'Organisation' and 'Position'. I would like the data submitted on the form to be added to the database. Because there is a variable number of rows I am not sure how to construct the PHP to enter all the necessary data.